# Group class member form elements for focusout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that fires when any of class elements lose focus:

```
<h5>ON Time</h5>
<div class = 'timeSetting'><form id = 'weekendStart'>
<input type='number' inputmode= 'numeric' pattern='[0-9]*' id = 'onHour' value='6' name = 'value' min='1' max='12'><input type='number' inputmode= 'numeric' pattern='[0-9]*' id = 'onMinute' value='30' name = 'value' min='0' max='59'>
<select id = 'weekendStartAmPm'>
<option value = 'weekendStartAm'>am</option>
<option value='weekendStartPm'>pm</option>
</select>
</form></div>
<h5>OFF Time</h5>
<div class = 'timeSetting'><form>
<input type='number' inputmode= 'numeric' pattern='[0-9]*' id = 'onHour' value='10' name = 'value' min='1' max='12'><input type='number' inputmode= 'numeric' pattern='[0-9]*' id = 'onMinute' value='00' name = 'value' min='0' max='59'>
<select id = 'weekdayStartAmPm'>
<option value='wkdayStartPm'>pm</option>
<option value = 'wkdayStartAm'>am</option>
</select>
</form></div>
```

I know this isn't right, but I'd like something like it:

```
$('.timeSetting').focusout(function(){
    console.log('lost focus');
});
```

where user can tab between form elements and edit transferring focus and once any (and all) members of the class lose focus, then the function fires...

Comment: You'd have to match all the elements, try something like `.timeSetting input, .timeSetting select` for your jQuery selector.

Comment: A few hints for you: We created a jQuery plugin called focusgroup to do just this. The basic principal is to listen for focus events and detected when a group is left (`document.activeElement` is no longer in the group). The key was to trigger custom events and listen for those instead e.g. "groupfocus" and "groupblur" events instead in the high level code. Another trick needed was waiting 1 frame on a blur event before detecting the new activeElement.

Comment: Found and old answer of mine and updated it for your HTML. Hope it is of help. Merry Xmas :)

Comment: Did you find your answer? If yes please write it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on something I wrote a couple of years back on SO to handle groups of focus: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/0y2dvxpf/6/

```
$('div.timeSetting').on('focus focusin', 'input,select', function() {
  var $editor = $(this).closest('.timeSetting');
  $editor.addClass("focused");

}).on('blur focusout','input,select', function() {
  var $editor = $(this).closest('.timeSetting');
  // wait for the new element to be focused
  setTimeout(function() {
    // See if the new focused element is in the editor
    if (!$.contains($editor[0], document.activeElement)) {
      $editor.removeClass("focused");
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

For now it just illustrates the focus with class changes, but you could just as easily trigger custom events instead and catch those on an ancestor.

Comment: I like the way that this works, but binding to 'blur' and 'focusout' causes two events to be triggered on loss of focus (along with the analog got focus).   Obviously, I remove one and it works well; is that there for multiple browser support?.  Also, can you tell me why I need TWO clicks off of a 'select' object to lose focus on that object and corresponding div?

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton: Feel free to modify the events. Most of that was from memory. You should not need 2 clicks, except possibly if the select was open, so would have to take a look at that. Should work on all browsers as we use something similar in production.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[class] input").focusout(function(){
    console.log('lost focus');
});
```

This will select any input existing in any element with a class attribute set to any value.

> Empty strings:
>
> If the attr must exist & could have any value (or none at all)

```
jQuery("[href]");
```

**Edit:** But if you want to detect the moment the focus goes from a div with class1 to another div with class2, you can use this:

```
var currentClass = false;
var leftClass = false;
$("[class]").focusout(function(){
    leftClass = $( this ).attr('class');
    console.log('lost focus ' + leftClass);
});

$("[class]").focusin(function(){
    currentClass = $( this ).attr('class');

    if(leftClass && leftClass != currentClass) {
        // Put your code here
        console.log(" div left " + leftClass);
    }
    console.log('in focus ' + currentClass);
});
```

Comment: This will detect each and every blur event. The OP wants to know when focus leaves the divs wrapping the forms.

Comment: This will detect the lost focus of every input in any div with a class attribute: he said: **and once any (and all) members of the class lose focus, then the function fires**

Comment: @GoneCoding has it right. I want to execute the function once class members as a group lose focus. My initial post wasn't well written.

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton The two divs must have the same class value or can have two different class ? What I want to know, is if you want to detect when leaving from class1 div to class2 div (because in your code, the two divs have the same class?

Comment: @B.Assem, So, I'm working on a form with many elements and I want to essentially run the function when focus leaves any element in the class.  I'd like to be able to tab between class elements... Basically, I'm updating the form when the class objects lose focus.  I need to play around with what' been offered up.